# Chaining async/await calls in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, async-await

I have an application that can add NYT bestseller items to a database. Currently, users can add a bestseller to the db even if it already exists in the db. I want to be able to chain API calls such that if a user tries to save an item, the application first checks if that item is in the db, and only if it isn't proceed to save the item.

Here is my existing code:

```
  const [currentInDb, setCurrentInDb] = useState(false);

 interface bookInt {
    title: string;
    author: string;
  }

  const handleDbCheck = async(book: bookInt) => { 
    setCurrentInDb(false); 
    let targetObj = {
      title: book.title, 
      author: book.author, 
      list: selectedCategory
    }
    try {
      let url = baseURL + "/read-all";
      axios.get(url).then((res) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < res.data.length; i++){
          let current = res.data[i]
          if (current.title === targetObj.title && current.list === targetObj.list){
            setCurrentInDb(true); 
          }    
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }


  const handleSaveBook = async (book: bookInt) => {
    if (currentInDb){
      console.log('handleSaveBook stopped early because item in db'); 
      return;
    } 
    try {
      let newObj = {
        title: book.title,
        author: book.author,
        list: selectedCategory,
      };
      let postURL = baseURL + "/create";
      axios.post(postURL, newObj).then((response) => {
        console.log('new item added'); 
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error: ", error);
    }
  };


  const handleCheckAndSave = async(book: bookInt): Promise<any> => {
    await handleDbCheck(book)
      .then(res => handleSaveBook(book))
  }
```

Oddly, upon page reload, the first time I try to add an item to the db that is already there, I CAN add a duplicate. Then if I try to add it again, it correctly does not allow me to add it. Ideas?

Comment: You're using both `async/await` and `.then` to handle responses, it makes it hard to predict how the code is going to be handled, especially in the `handleCheckAndSave`. Maybe try to use either `async/await` or `.then` and see if the problem still persists.

Comment: Got it, will try that now

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use .then in the async function.  you can simply use await & chain your asynchornous requests.

```
 const [currentInDb, setCurrentInDb] = useState(false);

 interface bookInt {
    title: string;
    author: string;
  }

  const handleDbCheck = async(book: bookInt) => { 
    setCurrentInDb(false); 
    let targetObj = {
      title: book.title, 
      author: book.author, 
      list: selectedCategory
    }
    try {
      let url = baseURL + "/read-all";
      const res = await axios.get(url)
      for (let i = 0; i < res.data.length; i++){
          let current = res.data[i]
          if (current.title === targetObj.title && current.list === targetObj.list){
            setCurrentInDb(true); 
          }    
        }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }


  const handleSaveBook = async (book: bookInt) => {
    if (currentInDb){
      console.log('handleSaveBook stopped early because item in db'); 
      return;
    } 
    try {
      let newObj = {
        title: book.title,
        author: book.author,
        list: selectedCategory,
      };
      let postURL = baseURL + "/create";
      const response = await axios.post(postURL, newObj)
      console.log(response)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error: ", error);
    }
  };


  const handleCheckAndSave = async(book: bookInt): Promise<any> => {
    await handleDbCheck(book)
    await handleSaveBook(book)
  }
```

Comment: Ok, I think part of the problem is that I did not know that setting state is async. Still working on it